# Using defines in Makefile.options file as a condition in Makefile variables

Tags: c, makefile

I am using clearmake and I am trying to do the following:

I have a Makefile.fast.options file that I use in my clearmake command. In there I have a USERFLAGS = -DFAST

and in another options file I don't have -DFAST in there (Makefile.slow.options).

In the actual Makefile, if FAST is defined, I want to set the output binary name to one name, or else I want to set it to another name. (If FAST is defined, I want the output to have .fast in the name, or else I want .slow.)

Is it possible to do this?  perhaps I am missing a much easier method for using an options file to determine output file name?

I was also thinking of defining the filename in the makefile options file, seems much easier:

FILENAME = File.Fast

but I want to use the options file to override a definition of FILENAME thats in the makefile itself..  so, if FILENAME is set in the options file use it, or else use the one in the makefile..  is this possible?

Comment: Okay I tried the filename makefile.options override and its working exactly how i want it to already, if its not defined in the options it uses the one in the makefile, if it is defined in the options file, it uses that one.

Comment: If you've solved the problem please mark the question as answered.

Comment: Well, 1st question isn't answered, but I suppose I don't need it to be answered anymore..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just change the name of the file you build.  You have to actually change the name of the target in the rule in the makefile.  This means that the target name needs to be variable.  The way you choose to make it variable is up to you.

If you're already including different options files based on fast vs. slow, then the simplest and most obvious way is to set the variable in those options files.  That's the way I would recommend.

If you want to do it based on the value of USERFLAGS, you could do something like this:

```
ifeq ($(filter -DFAST,$(USERFLAGS)),-DFAST)
    FILENAME = File.fast
else
    FILENAME = File.slow
endif
```

But, this seems more complex and difficult to read and understand (to me).

Comment: Thanks!  i ended up adding something like SPEED_SUFFIX to the options files and i incorporate that into the file name in the makefile..